# kubernetes federation : controllermanager crash : Could not find resources from API Server

Tags: kubernetes

Using 1.6.6 release for all

I am trying to deploy K8s federation using [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/federation/set-up-cluster-federation-kubefed)

I am using below command to create federation components in k8s cluster.

```
kubefed -v=9 init fellowship    --dns-provider="kube-dns"     --dns-zone-name="example.com"  --host-cluster-context="kubernetes-admin@kubernetes"   --api-server-service-type="NodePort"     --api-server-advertise-address="xx.yy.zz.aa" --etcd-persistent-storage=false   --kubeconfig="/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
```

**this is what happening**

```
federation-system   fellowship-apiserver-1032646596-pc3bh            2/2       Running            0          14m
federation-system   fellowship-controller-manager-2770733854-g593b   0/1       **CrashLoopBackOff**   7          14m

**an logs are as below** .

# more /var/log/pods/042190ab-576e-11e7-9706-0800270541db/controller-manager_2.log
{"log":"I0622 17:14:03.919937       1 controllermanager.go:93] v1.6.6\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-06-22T17:14:03.920258584Z"}
{"log":"I0622 17:14:03.921996       1 controllermanager.go:159] Loading client config for cluster controller \"cluster-controller\"\n","stream":"stderr","time":
"2017-06-22T17:14:03.922263896Z"}
{"log":"I0622 17:14:03.923489       1 controllermanager.go:161] Running cluster controller\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-06-22T17:14:03.923739515Z"}
{"log":"F0622 17:14:33.924245       1 controllermanager.go:166] Could not find resources from API Server: Get https://fellowship-apiserver/api: dial tcp: i/o timeout\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-06-22T17:14:33.927101427Z"}
```

Any guess  what is happening here , am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you check if your federation API server is reachable via its service?
Run `kubectl -n federation-system describe fellowship-apiserver` to see if there is anything obvious missing there. If there isn't any, run `kubectl run -i -t busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never` and `nslookup fellowship-apiserver` to see what you get.

Comment: Hello, I have tried many ways to deploy federation but  federation controller is crashing everytime . I want to confirm my deployment process with you first -> setup kube cluster using kubeadm command, then replaces kube-dns with core-dns and cluster is still working fine, kubernetes.svc.default.example.com is getting resolved to cluster IP. Then deployed federation and apiserver runs fine but controller crahloop back with generic error msg Error syncing pod.

Comment: Your deployment model looks fine. Are you using kubefed to deploy federation? That's the recommended way.

Are you able to create pods in your cluster, put a service in front of it and connect to the pods via the service DNS name? Can you do that, for example, for an nginx pod?